# Conditional DEBUG - Does it still compile into RELEASE code?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2010, conditional-compilation

I know that if I mark code as DEBUG code it won't *run* in RELEASE mode, but does it still get compiled into an assembly? I just wanna make sure my assembly isn't bloated by extra methods.

```
[Conditional(DEBUG)]
private void DoSomeLocalDebugging()
{
   //debugging
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the method itself still *is* built however you compile.

This is entirely logical - because the point of `Conditional` is to depend on the preprocessor symbols defined when the *caller* is built, not when the *callee* is built.

Simple test - build this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Test
{
    [Conditional("FOO")]
    static void CallMe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        CallMe();
    }
}
```

Run the code (without defining FOO) and you'll see there's no output, but if you look in Reflector you'll see the method is still there.

To put it another way: do you think the .NET *released assemblies* (the ones we compile against) are built with the DEBUG symbol defined? If they're not (and I strongly suspect they're not!) how would we be able to call `Debug.Assert` etc?

Admittedly when you're building *private* methods it would make sense not to include it - but as you can see, it still *is* built - which is reasonable for simplicity and consistency.